# Powershell listbox items to XML node

Tags: xml, powershell, active-directory

I have some troubles getting the content from a winform textlist item to multiple XML nodes.

When i try my code:

```
$fileName = "C:\tools\Options.xml";
$xmlDoc = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content $fileName);
$sitecheck = $xmldoc.options.locations.location.site
if ($sitecheck -eq $cboOffice.Text) 
{$txtInfobox.appendtext("Site already exists`r`n")}
else{
$newXmllocation=$xmlDoc.options.locations.AppendChild
($xmlDoc.CreateElement("location"));
$newXmlgroup = $xmlDoc.options.groups.AppendChild($xmlDoc.CreateElement("Group"));
$newXmllocation.SetAttribute(“site”,$cboOffice.text);
$newXmlgroup.SetAttribute(“Name”,$cboOffice.text);
$newXmlgrouplist = $newXmlgroup.AppendChild($xmlDoc.CreateElement("List"));
$newXmlgrouplist.SetAttribute(“Type”,"SecurityGroup");
$group = $txtGetLists.Item
$groups = $txtGetLists.Items
$newXmlgroupitem = foreach ($group in $groups) {
$newXmlgrouplist.AppendChild($xmlDoc.CreateTextNode($group));
    }
```

And The listbox `$txtgetlists.text` contains these lines:

```
Group1
Group2
Group3
Group4
Group5
```

in my XML file I end up with:

```
<Group Name="TestGroup">
<List Type="SecurityGroup">Group1Group2Group3Group4Group5</List> 
</Group>
```

Instead of the desired:

```
<Groups>
<Group Name="TestGroup">
<List Type="SecurityGroup">Group1</List>
<List Type="SecurityGroup">Group2</List> 
<List Type="SecurityGroup">Group3</List> 
<List Type="SecurityGroup">Group4</List> 
<List Type="SecurityGroup">Group5</List> 
</Group>
</Groups>
```

In other words i end up with all the items in one big line instead of separated nodes.

Maybe someone has a tip for me to get this done? I tried all kinds of "foreach item then do that"
variables, but i cannot seem to get it right.

Comment: It seems you are mixing two types in your question: `winform textlist item` and `winform GUI listbox`. You also mention two variables: `$txtGetLists` and `$txtgetitems`. Please cleanup your question.

Comment: Thanks for noticing, i changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention is to create new element and add those elements as children to the parent, you have to create each child separately and continue adding to the parent.  In your code, you iterate over a loop and continue to append child `List` but with different values each time. Instead of creating a new tag, its appending the value.

When you loop over the groups, you have to create a new element, `newXmlgrouplist`. If you reuse the same one, it will update it each time instead of adding a new instance. Use, `$newXmlgrouplist = $doc.CreateElement("List")` to create new instance each time.

Wrote a small code to show you how to create elements and adding them separately

```
[System.XML.XMLDocument]$doc=New-Object System.XML.XMLDocument
[System.XML.XMLElement]$parent = $doc.CreateElement("Groups")

$parent.SetAttribute("Name", "TestGroup")

$txtGetLists.Items | % { 
    [System.XML.XMLElement]$list = $doc.CreateElement("List")
    $list.SetAttribute("Type", "SecurityGroup")
    $list.InnerText = $_
    $parent.AppendChild($list)
}

$doc.AppendChild($parent)
```

and the result xml `$doc.InnerXml` is:

```
<Groups Name="TestGroup">
    <List Type="SecurityGroup">Group1</List>
    <List Type="SecurityGroup">Group2</List>
    <List Type="SecurityGroup">Group3</List>
    <List Type="SecurityGroup">Group4</List>
    <List Type="SecurityGroup">Group5</List>
</Groups>
```

**UPDATE**

Your foreach loop should look like this. It will add a new list item to your Groups each time it iterates through them.

```
$newXmlgroup = $xmlDoc.options.groups.AppendChild($xmlDoc.CreateElement("Group"))
$newXmllocation.SetAttribute("site",$cboOffice.text)
$newXmlgroup.SetAttribute("Name",$cboOffice.text)

foreach($group in $txtGetLists.Items) {
  $newXmlgrouplist = $newXmlgroup.AppendChild($xmlDoc.CreateElement("List"))
  $newXmlgrouplist.SetAttribute("Type","SecurityGroup")
  $newXmlgrouplist.InnerText = $group
}
```

This doesnt have any output, thus no need to set `$newXmlgroupitem = foreach`

If you print `$newXmlGroup.OuterXml`, it should show you the complete xml for Groups.

Comment: Jawad,  sure i will do that, if i may, just one more question. I already have a element <groups></groups> like you can see in my edited post. I need the <Group Name="TestGroup"> (with the list types) to be nested in there